# Windows 10 boot taking 50-60 seconds from power on

Tags: windows-10, boot, performance

My PC takes around 50~ seconds to boot - I'm running Windows 10 with the latest updates.

I have used Windows Performance Analyzer to analyze my boot, and I'm currently uploading the zip to post a link, but my upload speeds are horrendous so I'll provide the link when it's complete, for now I have attached some screenshots just incase anyone is able to make work of them.

My question is: can anyone see anything that might be causing the slow delay, if so do you have any suggestions on how to fix it?

Not sure if PC specs have anything to do with it, but here they are, just in case:

- i7-6700k,
- GTX1070ti,
- WD 500GB NVMe drive,
- 16GB DDR4 2133 RAM

I have already disabled `Intel Management Interface` which was a common cause for the slow boot.

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]
[image: Screenshot 3]

EDIT:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cMXy5nyjoFIas8sdb7Ly8y034eeltJhO/view?usp=drivesdk

My trace file can be downloaded here!

Comment: Do you have `Hybrid Shutdown`/`Fast Boot` enabled or disabled?  Please update your question with the relevant information instead of submitting a comment.  [You are also missing 145 seconds worth of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaKuy.jpg)

Comment: 50 seconds really isn't bad. What are you expecting for a boot time?

Comment: @HazardousGlitch my PC used to boot in 10-15 seconds, from power on to login. My laptop takes around 5~, so compared to that, 50 seconds is quite long :/ feels like forever when you're sat there waiting for it to boot

Comment: Was the 10-15 seconds after a fresh Windows install or after installing ALL the software you use? The more stuff you install that loads when you turn on your computer, the longer it takes to boot. What have you changed since it started to boot slower?

Comment: @HazardousGlitch I wouldn't be able to tell you I'm afraid, it used to be around 50 seconds last week but I bought a new hard drive so did a fresh install on windows and thought the faster hard drive would solve the issue but it didn't.. The slow boot started a while ago and since then it hasn't bothered me until now so I couldn't say if it was a software issue or not